# Undefined type 'Symfony\Component\Process\Process

Tags: laravel, symfony, process, undefined

I can't define the class so what must do for that?

After I downloaded `symfony/process`, that happened:

> Symfony\Component\Process\Process::__construct(): Argument #1 ($command) must be of type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\BAT\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ChartController.php on line 18

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\OrderItem;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process ;

class ChartController extends Controller
{

    public function PythonScript()
    {
        $process = new Process("C:\Users\ismail\Downloads\Untitled4.py");
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

        $data = $process->getOutput();

        dd($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you working in the namespace `Symfony\Component\Process\Exception`? for the class discovery run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the answer.

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Process::__construct():
Argument #1 ($command) must be of type array, string given,
called in C:\xampp\htdocs\BAT\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ChartController.php on line 18
```

---

What you are calling in line 18 of `C:\xampp\htdocs\BAT\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ChartController.php` is this:

```
$process = new Process("C:\Users\ismail\Downloads\Untitled4.py")
```

This calls the constructor (`__construct()`) function of `Symfony\Component\Process\Process`. You're only passing one argument and the error is telling you that the first argument is supposed to be an `array`, yet you are passing a `string`.

This is how the constructor looks in the original class.

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Process;
...
class Process implements \IteratorAggregate
{
    ...

    /**
     * @param array          $command The command to run and its arguments listed as separate entries
     * @param string|null    $cwd     The working directory or null to use the working dir of the current PHP process
     * @param array|null     $env     The environment variables or null to use the same environment as the current PHP process
     * @param mixed          $input   The input as stream resource, scalar or \Traversable, or null for no input
     * @param int|float|null $timeout The timeout in seconds or null to disable
     *
     * @throws LogicException When proc_open is not installed
     */
    public function __construct(array $command, string $cwd = null, array $env = null, mixed $input = null, ?float $timeout = 60)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Basically you need to add the python executable (or whatever it is you want to run `Untitled4.py` with.

```php
new Process(['path/to/python.exe', 'path/to/Untitled4.py']);
```